# Word Macro for Counting Shaded Words

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have a word file and some of the words written in that file are shaded in different colors. I want to find the count of the words that are shaded in colors. I am using the "Shading" feature of word and not the 'Highlight' feature.

I have written a macro but it's not working

```
Sub CountAllWordsInHighlight()
  Dim objWord As Range
  Dim nHighlightedWords As Long
  Dim objDoc As Document
  Dim nh As Integer
  Application.ScreenUpdating = False
  Set objDoc = ActiveDocument

  With Selection
     .HomeKey Unit:=wdStory
     With Selection.Find
          .Highlight = True

          Do While .Execute
                   nHighlightedWords = nHighlightedWords + Selection.Range.ComputeStatistics(wdStatisticWords)
                   Selection.Collapse wdCollapseEnd
          Loop
     End With
  End With
  MsgBox ("The total number of Colored words are" & nHighlightedWords & " .")
  Application.ScreenUpdating = True
  Set objDoc = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: Please describe HOW it's not working.

Comment: It's not returning the number of words that are shaded. However it is working fine when I'm using the Highlight feature. However I want to user the shading feature.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You mentioned that you are using the Shading feature to apply shading and not Highlight feature. But your code is looking for Highlighted word. Thats why your code is not working.

BTW, I do not see an option to search a Shaded word using Word VBA.

If you really want to use Shading and search for it, there are couple of options I can think of:

1. use a particular style while applying shading and search for the style using word vba.
2. getting the word processing xml out of the word file and search for shaded words using xpath or open office xml. But it is too broad to answer here if you want to go this approach.

Comment: Thank you so much for your quick response.

Comment: You're welcome :-)  The "right" way to thank for a useful contribution is to upvote (arrows to the left). To mark something as "the" answer, click the checkmark to the left. This 1) gives the person "points" and 2) lets others who may have a similar requirement know that the contribution answered the question.